# Spotvol calculation on xts object keeps producing POSIX and Error in set errors

Tags: r, timestamp, time-series, xts

I am trying to calculate the daily realised / historical volatility for a large dataset of equities by using the spotvol function from the highfrequency package.  For some reason I keep getting POSIX (timestamp) errors and I have tried a number of different methods to convert my sample to an xts object.

A sample of the dataset:

```
2015-01-02 10:00:00  80.15
2015-01-02 11:00:00  81.00
2015-01-02 12:00:00  80.50
2015-01-02 13:00:00  80.40
2015-01-02 14:00:00  80.15
2015-01-02 15:00:00  81.00
2015-01-02 16:00:00  80.50
2015-01-05 10:00:00  80.40
2015-01-05 11:00:00  80.95
2015-01-05 12:00:00  81.05
2015-01-05 13:00:00  80.85
2015-01-05 14:00:00  80.50
2015-01-05 15:00:00  80.40
2015-01-05 16:00:00  80.95
```

The code that I used to convert to the xts object is as follows:

```
vol_df2 <- vol_df1 %>%
  mutate(time_stamp = as.POSIXct(time_stamp, format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))

vol_df3 <- as.xts(vol_df2, order.by = vol_df2$time_stamp, tz = "", unique = F)
```

The code for trying to calculate the daily spotvol from **1 hour time buckets** is as follows:
NOTE: My actual data is of a high frequency nature, so I have provided aggregate data for each hour over 2 days.

```
  spotvol(vol_df3, method = "detper", on = "hours", k = 1,
          marketopen = "10:00:00", marketclose = "16:00:00")
```

The errors that I get are as follows:

```
Error in as.POSIXlt.character(x, tz, ...): 
character string is not in a standard unambiguous format
```

```
  do not know how to convert 'time' to class “POSIXct”
In addition: Warning messages:
1: All formats failed to parse. No formats found. 
2: All formats failed to parse. No formats found. 
3: In min.default(numeric(0), na.rm = FALSE) :
  no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
4: In max.default(numeric(0), na.rm = FALSE) :
  no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
5: All formats failed to parse. No formats found.
```

and

```
Error in set(x, j = name, value = value) : 
Supplied 1054304 items to be assigned to 1054377 items of column
'PRICE'. If you wish to 'recycle' the RHS please use rep() to make this
intent clear to readers of your code.
```

The research I have done so far has turned up nothing as I have simply followed the instructions for converting my timestamp and also converting to the xts object.
As I am running a Linux system I came across this:
 https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1619

I have also tried using the data.table method and this also produces the error regarding the unambiguous format of the POSIX timestamp.

It's like I am missing arguments in the commands for spotvol, however, I couldn't figure out whether there are defaults that can be changed from the documentation found here: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/highfrequency/versions/0.6.3/topics/spotvol

**EDIT: The only error I am receiving now is the last one in the list regarding the Error in set...When I change `fill=TRUE` to `fill=FALSE` in the `aggregatePrice` part of the `spotvol` function the spotvol seems to want to calculate for a bit but still throws the `Error in set` error.**

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.
Cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in this line of code:

```
vol_df3 <- as.xts(vol_df2, order.by = vol_df2$time_stamp, tz = "", unique = F)
```

If you look at what it contains it is this:

```
                    time_stamp            PRICE  
2015-01-02 10:02:00 "2015-01-02 10:02:00" "80.15"
2015-01-02 11:15:00 "2015-01-02 11:15:00" "81.00"
2015-01-02 12:31:00 "2015-01-02 12:31:00" "80.50"
2015-01-02 15:59:00 "2015-01-02 15:59:00" "80.40"
2015-01-05 10:01:00 "2015-01-05 10:01:00" "80.40"
2015-01-05 11:24:00 "2015-01-05 11:24:00" "80.95"
2015-01-05 14:21:00 "2015-01-05 14:21:00" "81.05"
2015-01-05 15:59:00 "2015-01-05 15:59:00" "80.85"
```

xts objects are a matrix and if you just select the whole data.frame including the timestamp it will be a character matrix. You need to exclude the timestamp column like this:

```
vol_df3 <- as.xts(vol_df2[, names(vol_df2) != "time_stamp"], 
                          order.by = vol_df2$time_stamp, tz = "", unique = F)
```

which results in this:

```
                     [,1]
2015-01-02 10:02:00 80.15
2015-01-02 11:15:00 81.00
2015-01-02 12:31:00 80.50
2015-01-02 15:59:00 80.40
2015-01-05 10:01:00 80.40
2015-01-05 11:24:00 80.95
2015-01-05 14:21:00 81.05
2015-01-05 15:59:00 80.85
```

And then spotvol will not return with an error.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @phiver, it makes sense.  Unfortunately the spotvol still returns an error (the last one mentioned above).  I thought it might have something to do with NA's, however, there are zero NA's in vol_df2 before the conversion.

Comment: In that case I need more data. Can you add the code that gives you the data? Or replicates the data in a way that would generate the error? Otherwise it is difficult to see where the error originates.

Comment: Ok, so I edited the question to reflect the fact that I am only seeing the `Error in set` error at the moment.  @phiver your code for converting to the xts object worked for the POSIX error, however, not the most recent error.  I managed to use `aggregatePrice` on my data today, so I added some extra dummy data to the question that reflects an hourly aggregate.  Does that help?  Cheers :)

Comment: The `spotvol` part of the code is what is producing the `Error in set` error.  Also, when I aggregate to 5 minute time buckets using `aggregatePrice`, there are multiple entries for say `10:00:00` and `10:05:00` etc etc.  Should that make a difference at all?